# Style dynamic value

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-8

Can I apply Style to the output of "Labeled" in the below ?

```
Manipulate[\[Lambda],
Control@{{\[Lambda], 401,
Style["     \[Lambda]", Black, Bold, 24]},
Range[401, 570, 1],
ControlType -> Slider,
ControlPlacement -> Bottom,
Appearance -> "Labeled",
ImageSize -> 200}]
```

That is on the right part of the Slider :

[image]

Comment: You can use `ControlType->LabeledSlider` and drop the `Appearance->"Labeled"` part. This will give you a much more compact and neater box.

Comment: But then the Number goes underneath for me.

Comment: @500: If you set the `ControlPlacement -> Bottom` for the `Manipulate` as opposed the the individual controller, then it does not effect the position of the label in a `LabeledSlider`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want the option `BaseStyle` (which appears in `Options[Slider]`). E.g.

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Cos[k x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotLabel -> "Cosine"], 
 {{k, 1, Style["x", Black, Bold, 24]}, 0, 4, 
  ControlType -> Slider, Appearance -> "Labeled", 
  ControlPlacement -> Bottom, ImageSize -> 200, 
  BaseStyle -> {Red, Large, Italic, FontFamily -> "Times"}}]
```

[image: cosine]

When looking at this I noticed that you can also use the [almost undocumented](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ControlPlacement.html#1465573995) `ControlType -> LabeledSlider`, just for something different.

Comment: Thank You Simon but it interfere with my plot labels. Is there a mean to avoid that ?

Comment: @500: The `DefaultBaseStyle` has to be set for the control object - not  the manipulate. See the edit.

Comment: Why would you want to use `DefaultBaseStyle` instead of `BaseStyle` (which seems to work fine as well)?

Comment: @Sjoerd: No good reason - and now that you bring it up, `BaseStyle` is probably preferable.

Comment: @Sjoerd: I think maybe I chose `DefaultBaseStyle` because @Brett said he had trouble getting `BaseStyle` to work... Thanks for pointing out that `BaseStyle` works - I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be at least partially affected by `LabelStyle` and `BaseStyle`.  (I'm having trouble changing the font, for some reason, but size, weight, color seem to work fine.)